# ¿Cómo desserializar una matriz Json con usando System.Text.Json y System.Text.Json.Serializatio ? (En c#)

Tags: c#, json

bien este es mi codigo, yo creo primero el archivo json. Es una lista de objetos de tipo WatherForecast. Luego quiero deserializar el json en una nueva lista (Lista2) y me da error.

```
        FileStream miArchivo = new FileStream("lista.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(miLista, options);

        using (StreamWriter strwriter = new StreamWriter(miArchivo))
        {
                strwriter.WriteLine(jsonString);
                strwriter.Close();   
        } // hasta aqui creo el archivo json 

        miLista2 = new List <WeatherForecast>(); 
        miLista2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString); // aqui me da error
```

Comment: Y que error te da?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Es `miLista` tipo de dato `List<WeatherForecast>`?  o algo equivalente? si la respuesta es si.. alli esta el detalla serializas un list y deserializas una clase no una lista

Answer (score 0):

Sí entendí bien tu pregunta creo que deberias cambiar esto para arreglarlo:

```
  FileStream miArchivo = new FileStream("lista.json", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(miLista, options);

    using (StreamWriter strwriter = new StreamWriter(miArchivo))
    {
            strwriter.WriteLine(jsonString);
            strwriter.Close();   
    } // hasta aqui creo el archivo json 

    miLista2 = new List <WeatherForecast>(); 
    miLista2 = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<WeatherForecast>>(jsonString); // aqui me da error
```

Explicacion: Estas intentando deserealizar una lista como un solo element de la lista asi que supongo que agregando List  se deberia arreglar, en lugar de solo tener WeatherForecast la cual es una clase que solo representa 1 elemento de la lista